# Get fql result into variable

Tags: facebook-fql

i'm trying to get fql (facebook query) my facebook friends that using my app result into a variable, with javascript.
i was trying to do something like this, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
FB.api('/me', function(user) { 
var fx = "";
this.query =  FB.Data.query('SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN ' + '(SELECT uid2 FROM    friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user');
this.query.wait(function(rows) {
fx = rows[0].uid;
});
});
alert(fx);
```

if the alert was inside of the query wait it worked, but i need this into a variable.
thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

that's because `var fax="";` is inside the block. try to put that outside the block.

```
var fx = "";
FB.api('/me', function(user) { 
this.query =  FB.Data.query('SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN ' + '(SELECT uid2 FROM    friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user');
this.query.wait(function(rows) {
fx = rows[0].uid;
});
});
alert(fx);
```